# How to print out the minibatchData's value?

Tags: cntk

```
       minibatch_size = 5
    data = reader.next_minibatch(minibatch_size, input_map={  # fetch minibatch
        x: reader.streams.query,
        y: reader.streams.slot_labels
    })
    evaluator = C.eval.Evaluator(loss, progress_printer)
    evaluator.test_minibatch(data)
    print("labels=", data[y].as_sequences())
```

I got an error for data[y].as_sequences() saying: 
    raise ValueError('cannot convert sparse value to sequences '
ValueError: cannot convert sparse value to sequences without the corresponding variable

How do I fix this? What is a variable? What should I put?

Answer (score 1):

data[y].as_sequences(variable=y) should do the trick, but I wouldn't recommend it.

On larger datasets as_sequences and asarray quickly cause out of memory exception to be thrown.

I ended up using this:
true_labels = cntk.ops.argmax(labels_input).eval(minibatch[labels_input]).astype(int)